# Java Mail Sender Strip off Second Content ID

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-mail

I am working on an Issue for the mail. Issue is related to sending the Images inLine in Java mail.
 I have two Images and converted them into the Byte Array and added them in the content header in sequence.  And added them in the Message. And logged the output, I can see two Contecnt -ID set along with the Image Data.

But when I am actually sending the data, last content-id is taken off.

```
helper.setText(msg.getText(), true);

if((InputStreamSource) model.get(ManageSystem.CAP_IMAGE_RESOURCE) != null){
    helper.addInline(ManageSystem.CAP_IMAGE_RESOURCE, (InputStreamSource) model.get(ManageSystem.CAP_IMAGE_RESOURCE), FileContentType.JPG);
}

if(model.get(ManageSystem.HITACHI_CAPITAL_LOGO_RESOURCE) != null){
        helper.addInline(ManageSystem.HITACHI_CAPITAL_LOGO_RESOURCE, (InputStreamSource) model.get(ManageSystem.HITACHI_CAPITAL_LOGO_RESOURCE), FileContentType.JPG);
}
```

Can any body please help me how to fix this.

Please Not I am using : [DEVSMTP](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DevNullSmtpUsage.jsp) server

Comment: Second content is not added in actual mail

Comment: Using JavaMailSenderImpl for sending the mail

Comment: You can edit your post instead of posting multiple comments.

Comment: @Anthony Accioly I am using helper as "MimeMessageHelper" not the MessageBody

Comment: Also, try to switch `multipartMode` (check [Spring API](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED)) this is a known point of client side incompatibility (don't know about server side).

Comment: @Anthony Accioly Perfect, it worked Thank you Anthony, not sure how to give you upVote.

Comment: @Anthony Accioly Yes, it is Multipart, thank you for your help

Comment: @Kumar, finally wrote an late answer. Feel free to comment on specifics that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The [MimeMessageHelper](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html) class, recommended by Spring Documentation [as the way to go for mime messages](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mail-javamail-mime) is, as it names implies, a simple a helper class to abstract some of the complexity of the [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) standard [MimeMessage](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html) class. `MimeMessage` is a powerful but admittedly verbose and complex class.

The main problem with mime messages is that, while there are several RFCs for it, incompatibility between e-mail clients are still an issue. And most often than not, working around those issues will require deep knowledge on the internals of mime messages as well as non-standard behaviors from popular email clients (this ranges from simple variations of headers all the way to changing the way content is disposed in the body of the message).

While far from perfect `MimeMessageHelper` is able to work with a fair range of headers and content disposition strategies. Those can be leverage by passing the supported constants to several constructors and methods that exposes a `multipartMode` parameter.

### Example

```
MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true, 
        MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED);
```

To better understand what those constants do I deeply recommend reading [RFC 2046](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387.txt) and [RFC 2387](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2046.txt)

### From `MimeMessageHelper` API

- `MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED`: Constant indicating a multipart message with a single root multipart element of type "mixed". Texts, inline elements and attachements will all get added to that root element.

  This was Spring 1.0's default behavior. It is known to work properly on Outlook. However, other mail clients tend to misinterpret inline elements as attachments and/or show attachments inline as well.
- `MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED`: Constant indicating a multipart message with a single root multipart element of type "related". Texts, inline elements and attachements will all get added to that root element.

  This was the default behavior from Spring 1.1 up to 1.2 final. This is the "Microsoft multipart mode", as natively sent by Outlook. It is known to work properly on Outlook, Outlook Express, Yahoo Mail, and to a large degree also on Mac Mail (with an additional attachment listed for an inline element, despite the inline element also shown inline). Does not work properly on Lotus Notes (attachments won't be shown there).
- `MULTIPART_MODE_MIXED_RELATED`: Constant indicating a multipart message with a root multipart element "mixed" plus a nested multipart element of type "related". Texts and inline elements will get added to the nested "related" element, while attachments will get added to the "mixed" root element.

  This is the default since Spring 1.2.1. This is arguably the most correct MIME structure, according to the MIME spec: It is known to work properly on Outlook, Outlook Express, Yahoo Mail, and Lotus Notes. Does not work properly on Mac Mail. If you target Mac Mail or experience issues with specific mails on Outlook, consider using MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED instead.

As you can see, this is such a controversial topic that Spring changed the default mode 3 times at its early stages.

As well as switching between spring strategies, sometimes you will need further control (at least I did in order to workaround some bady behaviour from popular web mail clients). This is where the handy [MimeMessagePreparator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessagePreparator.html) callback interface comes in. It lets you mix JavaMail and Springs API quite nicely:

```
mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {
   public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws MessagingException {
     MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, 
             true, "UTF-8");
     // now you have both JavaMail MimeMessage and Spring MimeMessageHelper
   }
 });
```

Finally, if Spring / JavaMail approach starts getting challenging, there are some pretty good libraries to make things easier. I can personally recommend both [Simple Java Mail](https://code.google.com/p/simple-java-mail/) and [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/); they are higher level and easier to use than JavaMail.